# GCC Complaint -- Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

I am trying to strip off the trailing `\n` char that `fgets()` appends. I am replacing this character with a string terminating char, `\0`.

Why is the compiler giving the error: "Assignment makes integer from pointer without cast".

```
word[strlen(word) - 1] = "\0";
```

Here's a more complete sample of the code is question in case some context is needed.

```
FILE *wordFile = fopen("/temp/words.txt", "r");
char word[100];
while (fgets(word, 100, wordFile)) {
    // Strip off the trailing the \n so it is not counted
    // as part of the string length
    word[strlen(word) - 1] = "\0";
    :
}
```

Comment: I smell fake code. I bet you wrote `"\0"` instead of `'\0'`...

Comment: HA! I am new to this IDE. Apparently my changes where not saved. I did indeed have "\0" first. I corrected the issue but apparently I was not rebuilding.

Comment: If there is no `'\n'` in your word (say, the input ended with an EOF or reached your buffer size without the `'\n'`), it'll happily chop off the last character in your word.

Comment: @sarnold: ah, *that's* why the C standard says that behavior is undefined if a source file isn't terminated by a newline! So that compilers can use this code ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies with the statement:

```
word[strlen(word) - 1] = "\0";
```

This is trying to assign the *pointer* to the C string to the array element, an integral type `char`, hence the error message `"Assignment makes integer from pointer without cast"`.

What you should have written was:

```
word[strlen(word) - 1] = '\0';
```

which assigns a *character* to the array element.

As an aside, you should watch out for lines that are longer than (about) 100 characters. You'll only read the first part of the line, it won't *have* a newline at the end, and you'll read the rest of the line as a separate line next time through your loop (and this may happen *many* times if you have a line that is, for example 1K long).

For what it's worth, you can fix those problems with code along the following lines:

```
if ((s = strlen (word)) > 0) {
    if (s[s-1] != '\n') {
        // Line was too long, do something intelligent.
    } else {
        s[s-1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanys heaps for the edit, @Antti, I can't believe (1) I made such a bone-headed mistake; and (2) no-one's picked it up for the last seven-plus years :-)