# Why "fputc "is not working here?It is throwing garbage letters

Tags: c, printf

I was working with basic **fputc** application in C. I am writing/appending "."
in the file number of times with **for** loop . But, the file is showing garbage letters instead of "." .

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
    {

        int i = 0 ;
        FILE *txtfile ;
        txtfile = fopen ( "fullstop.txt" , "a" ) ;
        for ( ; i < 100 ; i++ )
            {
                fputc (  "." , txtfile ) ;
            }
        fclose ( txtfile ) ;
        return 0 ;

    }
```

I don't see any syntactic errors in the code but maybe I am wrong. **GCC** shows following warnings and errors while compiling.This may help.

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fputc’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
fputc (  ".", txtfile ) ;
           ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:573:12: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 extern int fputc (int __c, FILE *__stream);
```

It works if I substitute with **fprintf** instead.

```
fprintf(txtfile,".");
```

I tried **fflush** too , but it didn't worked out too.

So,my question is why **fputc** isn't working?

Comment: `man fputc`... use `fputs` instead or give it the right argument: it needs the ASCII code for the character try with `46` instead of `"."`

Comment: @mguijarr Hell no. There is absolutely no excuse for typing `46` when you mean `'.'`, at least not in any code remotely meant to be readable.

Comment: You're passing a string where a character is required. Use single quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC Complaint -- Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061708/gcc-complaint-assignment-makes-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `fputc()` must a single character, not a string.

```
fputc('.', txtfile);
```

When you pass a string, it gets converted to a pointer, and then `fputc()` treats that pointer as a character value, which results in garbage.

Comment: @hvd this might explain a little bit, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions